# Payment Gateway options other than Paypal, for sending out mass payments

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

We were using Paypal Payment pro earlier for the same thing, but for some reason Paypal has been given some new guideline which kinda hinder with the way we need to send out payments at the moment.

We receive payments from clients and then send out payments back to vendors on a weekly basis ( deducting our cut ). Can you let me know what options are available to for such transactions other than paypal ? which is the best in terms cost of setup etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not allowed to credit credit cards which you haven't debited from you need to either send ACH direct deposits, or mail out checks.

Answer (score 1):

Like Anagio said you need an ACH vendor. I use a company called ACH Direct. They have an open API so you can write your own interface to it and process in batch.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Payza in the past and found that it was a good alternative to Paypal.